# Entering string instead of integer (Java)

Tags: java

I am an absolute beginner, no experience in any programming language.

I wrote a program as an exercise for converting Arabic numbers to Roman numbers. It works. However I want to add a part for dealing with problem if a string  is entered instead of integer. And don't know how to do this. I tried to use try/catch, but I don't know how to use it correctly. Now the program asks me twice to enter a number. What to do?

Here is he main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numArabic; 
    boolean validEntry;

    try {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer number between 1 and 3999!");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
            numArabic = scan.nextInt();
            validEntry = true;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Entered value is not an integer!");
        }

    System.out.println("Enter an integer number between 1 and 3999!");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
    numArabic = scan.nextInt();                            

    if ((numArabic < 1) || (numArabic > 3999)) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Wrong number. ");
            System.out.print("Enter an integer number between 1 and 3999!");
            System.out.println();
            }
    else {
            String numRoman1 = toRomanOne(numArabic % 10);
            String numRoman2 = toRomanTwo(((numArabic / 10) % 10));
            String numRoman3 = toRomanThree(((numArabic / 100) % 10));
            String numRoman4 = toRomanFour(numArabic / 1000);
            System.out.print("The number " + numArabic + " is equal to: ");
            System.out.print(numRoman4+numRoman3+numRoman2+numRoman1 + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: Now the program asks me twice to enter a number. Thats because you are doing -             System.out.println("Enter an integer number between 1 and 3999!");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
            numArabic = scan.nextInt(); twice

Comment: run:
Enter an integer number between 1 and 3999!
jjk
Entered value is not an integer
Enter an integer number between 1 and 3999!
kkj
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at arabictoroman.ArabicToRoman.main(ArabicToRoman.java:35)
Java Result: 1

Comment: "Thats because you are doing - System.out.println("Enter an integer number between 1 and 3999!"); Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); numArabic = scan.nextInt(); twice" OK, but what to do? If I don't ask it a second time, I get "variable no initialized".

Comment: it's related to the second Scanner.nextInt; the first one is inside the try/catch and it's handked

Comment: If I delete the second scan.nextIn(), then I get "variable numArabic might not have been initialized".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your control mechanism is true but only works once. You have to put it inside a loop so that it can allow user to enter an integer at last.

```
boolean validEntry;

do {
   try {
      System.out.println("Enter an integer number between 1 and 3999!");
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
      numArabic = scan.nextInt();
      validEntry = true;
   }
   catch (InputMismatchException e) {
      validEntry = false;
      System.out.println("Entered value is not an integer!");
   }
}
while(!validEntry);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scanner#hasNextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) method to check that.

This method returns `true` if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an int value.

```
if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
   // Do the process with Integer.
} else {
   // Do the process if it is not an Integer.
}
```

Note that, this will cover all the Inputs which are not `Integer`, not only `String`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numArabic; 
    boolean validEntry = false;

    while (validEntry = false){
    try {

            System.out.println("Enter an integer number between 1 and 3999!");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
            numArabic = scan.nextInt();
            validEntry = true;
        }

        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Entered value is not an integer!");
            validEntry = false;
        }
    }                 

    if ((numArabic < 1) || (numArabic > 3999)) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Wrong number. ");
            System.out.print("Enter an integer number between 1 and 3999!");
            System.out.println();
            }
    else {
            String numRoman1 = toRomanOne(numArabic % 10);
            String numRoman2 = toRomanTwo(((numArabic / 10) % 10));
            String numRoman3 = toRomanThree(((numArabic / 100) % 10));
            String numRoman4 = toRomanFour(numArabic / 1000);
            System.out.print("The number " + numArabic + " is equal to: ");
            System.out.print(numRoman4+numRoman3+numRoman2+numRoman1 + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: wrong answer please run the program it is not going inside while .

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
     boolean b=true;
     while(b)
    {
       try 
        {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer number between 1 and 3999!");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
        numArabic = scan.nextInt();
        validEntry = true;
        }
      catch (InputMismatchException e) 
         {
          System.out.println("Entered value is not an integer!");

         }
      if(validEntry) 
       {
        if ((numArabic < 1) || (numArabic > 3999)) 
        {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Wrong number. ");
        System.out.print("Enter an integer number between 1 and 3999!");
        System.out.println();
        }
        else 
        {
        String numRoman1 = toRomanOne(numArabic % 10);
        String numRoman2 = toRomanTwo(((numArabic / 10) % 10));
        String numRoman3 = toRomanThree(((numArabic / 100) % 10));
        String numRoman4 = toRomanFour(numArabic / 1000);
        System.out.print("The number " + numArabic + " is equal to: ");
        System.out.print(numRoman4+numRoman3+numRoman2+numRoman1 + ".");
        }
       b=false;
   }//end of if 
 }//end of while
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

you need to initialize `numArabic` to some value first.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numArabic = 0;
    boolean validEntry;

    try {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer number between 1 and 3999!");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        numArabic = scan.nextInt();
        validEntry = true;
    }

    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Entered value is not an integer!");
    }


    if ((numArabic < 1) || (numArabic > 3999)) {

    } else {

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The Program what you entered is free from syntax errors and logical errors.But for asking only one time to enter the integer value just rewrite the code as following.We are attaching second sop function in catch block.So if the input is mismatch it will ask for again re-enter.
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int numArabic; 
    boolean validEntry;

    try {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer number between 1 and 3999!");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
            numArabic = scan.nextInt();
            validEntry = true;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Entered value is not an integer!");


System.out.println("Enter an integer number between 1 and 3999!");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
        numArabic = scan.nextInt();
        }
```